# Google chrome scroll lag when calling scrollintoview multiple times

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll, js-scrollintoview

I'm using Javascript scrollIntoView function to scroll a container so that the element that is currently on focus, appears in the center of the container.

I'm using addEventListener to listen to arrow keys to change which element I want to be on focus, then, scrollIntoView is launched to scroll into the currently focused element.

This works fine if I change the focused element slowly, but if I start changing the focused element quickly, the scroll "almost" stops and waits until I stop changing the focused element, then that element will be centered in the container.

This only happens on Google Chrome, I tested it in Firefox and it works perfectly well no matter how quickly I changed the focused element.

Suggestions don't have to be compatible with other browsers, also changing Google Chrome setting to solve this problem is also fine because this is just for personal use locally and I'll only run it using Google Chrome.

**Possible problem**

Although I'm not sure, I think Google Chrome handle the scrollIntoView differently than for example Firefox. When I call it quickly and the previous scroll hadn't finished yet, it stops the previous scrollIntoView in the middle of execution, this leaves the elements not centered in the container, then calls scrollIntoView again and does the calculation again to figure out the current scroll position and how much it needs to scroll to make the currently focused element in the center of the container. If multiple calls are made, only the last call to scrollIntoView call is fully executed, this means that not fully finished scrollIntoView calls is what's making the scroll lag.

**scrollIntoView options:**

```
elementCurrentlyOnFocus.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth",block:"center"});
```

**Browsers I tested my code with:**

Chrome version: 76.0.3809.100 (Lags)

Firefox Version: 68.0.2 (Smooth)

Comment: This issue still exists in Chrome (& Chromium 79). Firefox does not lag.

Comment: i dont call it multiple times... but it stucks also for me. very strange. i fire the function ant he scroll 50px down or something like that, and stop scrolling before reaching the target...

Comment: Is this still not fixed?